# Changing color of selected node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jstree

I want to change the background color of my selected node in jstree.

```
$('#syncrep').jstree({
                                        'core' : {
                                            'data' : repository
                                        }
                                    }).bind("loaded.jstree",
                                    function(event, data) {
                                        $(this).jstree("open_all");
                                    }).on("select_node.jstree",
                                    function(e, data) {

                                        Repository_SelectedNode = $('#syncrep')
                                                .jstree('get_node', data.node);

                                        Repository_SelectedNode_Copy = angular
                                                .copy(Repository_SelectedNode);
                                                });
```

I tried using an inbuilt API of jstree 'redraw' but it is not serving my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change style for the `.jstree-default .jstree-clicked` class?

See below, also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/7vx1cz39/).

```
.jstree-default .jstree-clicked {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: changing the class did help. I needed to override the css.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Whole Row I also needed the following:

```
.jstree-default .jstree-clicked {
    background: #FFFFFF !important; 
}
.jstree-default .jstree-wholerow-clicked {
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%) !important;
}
```